# assigning a value to function parameter changes the properties of arguments object?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, scope, arguments

This is probably one of the strangest things that I have seen to do with javascript.

Forgive me if there is already an answer, if there is then I am not sure what to look for.

I tried this:

```
var test = function ( a, b, c ) {
    alert ( Array.prototype.slice.call ( arguments );

    b = 5;

    alert ( Array.prototype.slice.call ( arguments );
};

test ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

And got this:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 5, 3
```

I looked at MDN `arguments` as well as `Function` and neither make any mention of this.

The spec states ( emphasis mine ):

> Every execution context has an associated VariableEnvironment. Variables and functions declared in ECMAScript code evaluated in an execution context are added as bindings in that VariableEnvironment’s Environment Record. ***For function code, parameters are also added as bindings to that Environment Record***.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5

Which, based on the observed behavior, would suggest that ***both*** the parameters and the arguments properties are bound to the same records.

Conversely, this:

```
var test = function ( a, b, c ) {
    alert ( Array.prototype.slice.call ( arguments ) );

    arguments [ 1 ] = 5;

    alert ( b );
};

test ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

produces this:

```
1, 2, 3
5
```

<strike>So my question is why is this so?</strike>

### Edit:

To rephrase so as not to draw opinionated answers.

What are possible use cases for this?

### Edit:

For the record:

> JSLint also raises this warning when it encounters an assignment to a property of the ***arguments*** object. In this example we attempt to define an x property:

```
function example() {
    "use strict";
    arguments.x = 1;
}
```

https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/bad-assignment.md

And it treats the assignment `arguments [ 1 ] = 5` the same way, though it is not a fatal error in this case.

Considering that I have used javascript for many years and only discovered this today, although it is interesting, it makes me wonder why this little caveat is important enough to be a part of the language when it seems to be rather counter intuitive, imo downright strange.  But I suppose its not really any more strange than some other things javascript that we've all seen.

Comment: What exactly you find counter intuitive? If there are two ways to get to arguments of the function they better produce the same results...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, but my assumption is that `a, b, c` are variables, as distinct references from `arguments [ 0 ]`, `arguments [ 1 ]` and `arguments [ 2 ]` though initially the values are merely correlated.  The part that bothers me about it is if a function passes its arguments along to another function, but before doing so, attempts to use/borrow the parameters to use as internal variables, again assuming that would not affect the properties of the arguments object.

Comment: Makes sense... have not looked at it from this point of view. I personally never seen people mixing access to `arguments` vs accessing by name so most likely hardly anyone cares. I'm glad specification defines a behavior (rather than leave "undefined" or "implementation specific") so one can figure out what correct code is, but yet to see usage of it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed. I started to worry when MDN had nothing to say.